# Conditionally set values in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a stored procedure that will update values in a table row depending on whether or not the parameters are provided. For example, I have a situation where I want to update all the values, but also a situation where I'm only required to update two values. I was hoping to be able to do this with only one procedure, rather than writing two, which doesn't particularly appeal to me. The best I have managed to come up with myself is something like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdatePerson
@PersonId INT,
@Firstname VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Lastname VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Email VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE Person 
Set 
    Firstname = COALESCE(@Firstname, Firstname),
    Lastname = COALESCE(@LastName, Lastname),
    Email = COALESCE(@Email, Email)
    WHERE PersonId = @PersonId

END
```

I realize that the values will be updated each time anyway, which isn't ideal. Is this an effective way of achieving this, or could it be done a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code is fine. The only thing I would add is a check for the case when all three params are `NULL`, in which case no update should be done.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does actually have some logic to deal with non updating updates.

[More details than you probably wanted to know!](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)